# jquery not working in brackets/sublime ,not able to use click function

Tags: jquery, html, css

The code works in jsfiddle perfectly. I've tried brackets / sublime and neither have worked. And yes my directories math with each other. and also when I upload it to github it still doesn't work.

```
   <script src="search.js" type='text/javascript'> </script>
   <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet'  type='text/css'>








$(document).ready(function(){

$('#global-radcircle-search-bar').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.search-dropdown').toggleClass('hidden');
     });
 });  

.hidden{

display: none; 
}
input{
border-radius: 5px;
margin-top: 10px;

}
.search-dropdown{

margin-right: 665px;
border-radius: 5px;

}

<section class="search1">
<div id="global-radcircle-search-bar"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
<div class="search-dropdown hidden">   
    <input placeholder="search..." type="text"/>

</div>

</section>
```

This is basically the same code I used 
http://jsfiddle.net/rk12aa5g/7/

Thank You

Comment: Why would Javascript 'work'  in a text **editor** ?

Comment: What 'doesn't work'. Are you linking Jquery anywhere?

Comment: @Paulie_D the click function and how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Are you importing the JQ library into your site somewhere?

Comment: @Paulie_D ignore this post. my bad

Comment: @Paulie_D figured it out